# How to build a restart button in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a little game to learn Python. I use PygameZero to run the code and to show the sprites. I tried to make a restart button but nothing seems to work. Can somebody help me?

This is how I've tried, and it worked because `gameOver` is first true and then false. But I can't use `draw()` again to continue the game.

```
def on_mouse_down(pos):
    global gameOver, restartButton, restart
    if restartButton.collidepoint(pos):
        gameOver = False
        restart = True
        if restart == True:
            draw()
```

I expected the `draw()` function to run again, but that is not what happens, instead, nothing happens.

Comment: Is this using `pygame`?

Comment: did you tried to debug and see if the program even runs that line?